# How to correctly retrieve data using an node api of a sqlite3 database

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am coding a simple node.js application that retrieves store data from a sqlite3 database. I coded the API using express and when I test it with curl it doesn't retrieve the data.

I have tested the SQL model and it works.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();


let db = new sqlite3.Database('********', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the in-memory SQlite database.');
});

function recordNotFound(message) {
    Error.call(this);
    this.message = message;
    this.status = 404;
}

var Users = function () {};

Users.prototype.getAll = function(callback) {
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    db.all(sql, [], function(err, rows) { 
        if (err) {
            console.log('chao1');
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            console.log('chao2');
            callback(err, rows);
        }
    });
};

var users = new Users();
users.getAll(function(err, rows) {
                console.log(rows);
                callback(null, 1);
            })
        });
```

Also, when doing

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

in the sqlite3 terminal it retrieves the information correctly.

However, in the file user_api_router.js I have,

```
var express = require('express');

userApiRouter = express.Router();

var Users = require('../model/users_sql_model')

var users = new Users();

userApiRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    users.getAll(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('control1');
            res.status(500).json({message: 'Error retrieving records!'});
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).json(result);
    });
});
```

And in the index.js file I have,

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var usersApiRouter = require('./app/router/user_api_router');

app.use('/v1/user', usersApiRouter);

var port = 3000;

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on port ' + port);
});
```

When I run index.js and type

```
curl http://localhost:3000/v1/user
```

It says,

```
{"message":"Error retrieving records!"}
```

I don't know what to do to retrieve the records correctly using curl. Help me please!

Comment: replace useless `console.log('control1');` with `console.log(err);`, whats it say?

Comment: where are you exporting the model (Users) from the users_sql_model?

Comment: It says, { Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: usuarios errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' }

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that. I am doing it at the bottom of the file:  module.exports = Users;

Comment: I figured it out. I had the database file inside the model folder. I moved it where index.js is and it worked. Thanks for replying.